# How to use the new RegisterForActivityResult in Xamarin Android, i.e. for GoogleSignIn

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication, xamarin.android, google-signin

I read that `StartActivityForResult` is deprecated and it is anyway not nice to have the callback in `MainActivity.OnActivityResult()` when you start the login process elsewhere.

Unfortunately I couldn't get any of the examples translated, seems Xamarin is missing essential things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing part was that there is no implementation of `IActivityResultCallback` anywhere, so I created my own. Hope this will be included in Xamarin some time.

```
public class ActivityResultCallback : Java.Lang.Object, IActivityResultCallback
{
    readonly Action<ActivityResult> _callback;
    public ActivityResultCallback(Action<ActivityResult> callback) => _callback = callback;
    public ActivityResultCallback(TaskCompletionSource<ActivityResult> tcs) => _callback = tcs.SetResult;
    public void OnActivityResult(Java.Lang.Object p0) => _callback((ActivityResult)p0);
}
```

Using the `TaskCompletionSource` approach you can even await the callback. Here is how I used it for GoogleSignIn:

```
readonly Func<Task<GoogleSignInResult>> _googleSignInAsync = PrepareGoogleSignIn(
    MainActivity.SharedInstance, "123-321.apps.googleusercontent.com"); //TODO: read from google-services.json

static Func<Task<GoogleSignInResult>> PrepareGoogleSignIn(ComponentActivity activity, string serverClientId)
{
    var googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
        .RequestIdToken(serverClientId)
        .RequestEmail()
        .Build();

    var googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.GetClient(activity, googleSignInOptions);

    TaskCompletionSource<GoogleSignInResult> taskCompletionSource = null;

    var activityResultLauncher = activity.RegisterForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback(activityResult => taskCompletionSource?.SetResult(
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInResultFromIntent(activityResult.Data))));

    return () => {
        taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<GoogleSignInResult>();
        activityResultLauncher.Launch(googleSignInClient.SignInIntent);
        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    };
}
```

I have this in the Android implementation of my authentication service. You can also prepare it in `MainActivity.OnCreate()` with parameter `this`. Make sure it is called before the app goes to running state.

Later you can just await `_googleSignInAsync()`. Neat!

---

Some bonus code how to use it and forward to Firebase auth:

```
using Android.Gms.Auth.Api;
using Android.Gms.Auth.Api.SignIn;
using Android.Gms.Extensions;
using AndroidX.Activity;
using AndroidX.Activity.Result;
using AndroidX.Activity.Result.Contract;
using Firebase.Auth;

var signInResult = await _googleSignInAsync();
Console.WriteLine($"{signInResult.Status} {signInResult.SignInAccount?.DisplayName}");
if (!signInResult.IsSuccess || signInResult.SignInAccount == null)
    throw new GoogleSignInCanceledException();

var credential = GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(signInResult.SignInAccount.IdToken, null);
var authResult = await FirebaseAuth.Instance.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential);
AuthToken = (await authResult.User.GetIdToken(false).AsAsync<GetTokenResult>()).Token;
```

Any improvements? I'm happy to hear from you. Or are you looking for the [iOS implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73446769/1855801)?

Comment: Can you show you android code, c# if you have it.