# How to use GoogleSignIn in Xamarin iOS (with firebase)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication, xamarin.ios, google-signin

I want to use it in the iOS implementation of my authentication service. It's hard to find examples and they don't easily translate to Xamarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it worked for me:

```
using GIDSignIn = Google.SignIn.SignIn;

static async Task<SignInDelegateEventArgs> GoogleSignInAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<SignInDelegateEventArgs>();
    void Handler(object sender, SignInDelegateEventArgs args) => tcs.SetResult(args);

    var vc = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow?.RootViewController ?? throw new Exception("ViewController not found");
    GIDSignIn.SharedInstance.PresentingViewController = vc;
    GIDSignIn.SharedInstance.Disconnected += Handler;
    GIDSignIn.SharedInstance.SignedIn += Handler;

    try
    {
        GIDSignIn.SharedInstance.SignInUser();
        return await tcs.Task;
    }
    finally
    {
        GIDSignIn.SharedInstance.SignedIn -= Handler;
        GIDSignIn.SharedInstance.Disconnected -= Handler;
    }
}
```

Since this is event driven, I put a `TaskCompletionSource` around, so you can easily await the result (plus bonus code for Firebase):

```
var signInResult = await GoogleSignInAsync();
Console.WriteLine($@"{signInResult.Error} {signInResult.User?.Profile.Email}");

if (signInResult.Error != null || signInResult.User == null)
    throw new GoogleSignInCanceledException(signInResult.Error.ToString());

// ReSharper disable once HeuristicUnreachableCode
var credential = GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(signInResult.User.Authentication.IdToken, signInResult.User.Authentication.AccessToken);
var authResult = await Auth.DefaultInstance.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential);
AuthToken = await authResult.User.GetIdTokenAsync();
```

Include this in `AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching()`:

```
var googleServiceDictionary = NSDictionary.FromFile("GoogleService-Info.plist");
GIDSignIn.SharedInstance.ClientId = googleServiceDictionary["CLIENT_ID"].ToString();
```

Include this in `Info.plist`:

```
<!-- Google Sign-in Section -->
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <!-- Copied from GoogleService-Info.plist key REVERSED_CLIENT_ID -->
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.123-321</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<!-- End of the Google Sign-in Section -->
```

Any improvements? I'm happy to hear from you. Or are you looking for the [Android implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73296776/1855801)?