# Xamarin Forms Firebase Auth OAuth sign in for Apple, Microsoft, Twitter, ...?

Tags: xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication, oauth, apple-sign-in

For Google sign in I used their SDK, but Firebase supports Apple (and others) over OAuth and I'm not sure how to translate their examples to Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Xamarin.Essentials` provides support for Apple sign in, but only on **iOS**. With Firebase it works like this:

```
if (!UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
    throw new AppleSignInCanceledException("Apple sign in requires iOS 13+, sorry.");

var signInResult = await AppleSignInAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync();
var credential = OAuthProvider.GetCredential("apple.com", signInResult.IdToken, signInResult.AccessToken);
var authResult = await Auth.DefaultInstance.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential);
AuthToken = await authResult.User.GetIdTokenAsync();
```

On **Android**, you can use this simple approach, which uses a browser window:

```
var provider = OAuthProvider.NewBuilder("apple.com");
await FirebaseAuth.Instance.StartActivityForSignInWithProvider(MainActivity.SharedInstance, provider.Build());
var result = await FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.GetIdToken(false);
AuthToken = (result as GetTokenResult)?.Token;
```

This should also work for Microsoft, Twitter and other providers supported by Firebase.

On **iOS**, the OAuth implementation could look like this (untested, please comment):

```
var provider = OAuthProvider.Create("microsoft.com");
var authResult = await Auth.DefaultInstance.SignInWithProviderAsync(provider, null);
AuthToken = await authResult.User.GetIdTokenAsync();
```

Any improvements? I'm happy to hear from you. Or are you looking for the [Google implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73446769/1855801)?